# DFT Name to be used in SSIS Event Manager

Tags: ssis

I would like to know if there is any way to use the DFT Task Name (as a variable) inside the Event Handlers task? 
But now when I use Systech:TaskName it displays the name of the OnError task and I would like to have the name of source DFT task used inside the OnError task.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OnError event handler, you have the `@[System::SourceName]` variable available to you that shows you the task that generated the error.

[image]

You also have SourceID available to you there in case you have nested Tasks with the same name